How to solve error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'response') onFormSubmit @ Code.gs:3
I faced an error when I build up google script for google form the purpose from the script only that if the birthdate that entered from the form is after 1-Oct-2020 stop submitting form after I finish and I trying the form with date 24-Nov-2023 the form record the data
I make trigger on submit form and when I try to debug the script I get this error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'response')
onFormSubmit    @ Code.gs:3

the Script:
function onFormSubmit(e) {

  var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var birthdateItem = itemResponses[6]; // Assuming birthdate is the last item
  var birthdateValue = birthdateItem.getResponse();

  try {
    // Convert birthdate to a date object
    var birthdate = new Date(birthdateValue);

    // Create a date object for the cutoff date
    var cutoffDate = new Date(2020, 0, 10); // January 10, 2020

    if (birthdate > cutoffDate) {
      var errorMessage = "Birthdate must be before 1/10/2020.";
      e.response.setResponseText(errorMessage);
      return;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error parsing birthdate:", error);
    // Handle error, e.g., send notification or reject submission
  }
  console.log(e)
}


Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/1608904

and when I try to debug the script I get this error Did you run the function from the script editor? Yes... you get the error because e only has a value when there is a form submission.

Short answer

The script was run from the Script Editor.
So the Event Arguments (e) weren't returned.
So e.response was undefined.

Birth date validation
The purpose of the script is to validate the Respondent's Birth date.

Forms doesn't offer any kind of data validation for `Dateitems'. So the OP is trying to dynamically test whether the respondents Birth date is greater or less than the Cutoff date.
If the Birth date is invalid, the OP is trying to create an error message that the respondent will read.
This CANNOT and will NOT work.



onFormSubmit is executed after the form is submitted. So not only it is too late to send a message to the respondent; Forms has no feature to provide real-time/dynamic update to the respondent.




setResponseText does not exist.





